# auto generate id for document and not collection in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have gone through the firestore docs and I'm yet to find an example where we have something like this.

```
collection
       |--document
                |--{auto-generated-id}
                                  |--property1:value1
                                  |--property2:value2
                                  |--peoperty3:value3
```

Rather what I often see is:

```
collection     
         |--{auto-generated-id}
                            |--property1:value1
                            |--property2:value2
                            |--peoperty3:value3
```

In the former, I cannot call `add()`-(which generates unique id) on a document. However this can be done in a collection as shown in the latter sketch above.

My question is thus:
Is there a way firestore can help autogenerate an id after creating a document
i.e
How can I achieve something like this:

```
db.collection("collection_name").document("document_name").add(object)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.lang.Object)) method, it means that it:

> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified POJO as contents, assigning it a document ID automatically.

If you want to get the document id that is generated and use it in your reference, then use DocumentReference's [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) method:

> Overwrites the document referred to by this DocumentRefere

Like in following lines of code:

```
String id = db.collection("collection_name").document().getId();
db.collection("collection_name").document(id).set(object);
```

Comment: Yes!! @Alex Mamo, Your solution was really helpful. What I did was simply to create a new collection and call add i.e db.collection("new_collection_name").add()...

Comment: Really helpful. Although, your answers are always short, sweet and helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The .document() method doesn't appear to exist anymore - current recommendation is to use doc(), which will create a DocRef, and then get the .id property.

Comment: @MikeBurton For Android, it's still `.document()` and **not** `doc()`.

Answer (score 9):

Now that v9 of the firebase javascript API is out the syntax has changed a little.

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id.
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cities"), {
  name: "Tokyo",
  country: "Japan"
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
```

You can wrap it in a try/catch block to handle errors.

In summary:

- If you want to auto generate an ID use `addDoc()` + `collection()`
- If you want to set the ID use `setDoc()` + `doc()`

Answer (score 6):

This answer might be a little late but you can look at this code here which will generate a new document name:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

it's more convenient to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling `add()`

Read more about it on [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know the id of the document, just call `set()` instead of `add()`.  It will create the document if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in Flutter/dart you can make a Future to **1).** Create a document in firestore (firestore will auto generate an ID for the document), **2).** Then call the created document, **3).** And finally display the id **OR** Update the ID field

```
Future createPost(PostModel postModel) async {
  _firestore.collection("posts").add({

  "pid": postModel.pid, // Creating a field for post ID

  }).then((querySnapshot) { // Here whe call the document just after creation

  String generatedID = querySnapshot.id.toString(); // Here we call the ID of the document

  print("ID OF CREATE POST: " + generatedID); // Here we display the generated document ID

  querySnapshot.update({ // Here we update the pid(Post ID) field in the new generated document
    "pid": generatedID
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer is proper, but it work for me.

```
/// prepare db
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("users");

/// add uniq id

final id = db.doc().id;

/// prepare dates to save
final user = TestUser(
    name: name.text,
    age: int.parse(age.text),
    id: id
);

/// add user
db.doc(id).set(user.toJson());
```

`

Comment: Given that there are already several answers to this question, can you [edit] your answer to explain why you prefer this approach over the existing suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you add document to the collection, the response object will include the id of the created document. So you can de-structure the response object in javascript and use this id directly.

```
(async () => {
   const dataObject = YOUR_DATA;
   const { id } = await firebase.firestore().collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").add(dataObject);
   console.log(id); //the newly added doc's id
})()
```